# Data table logical operations over columns

Tags: if-statement, datatable

I am trying to use data table to manipulate a large dataset, but has run into trouble. Consider the following (greatly simplified) data table which contains 4 rows with id and 3 combinations of code and date

```
>my_data
      id code.1 date.1   code.2 date.2   code.3 date.3
1:     4    1 2000-06-26    11 1999-11-09    11 1999-10-26
2:     7   22 1998-07-24    11 1998-07-22    49 1998-07-20
3:     9   47 1998-10-28    49 1999-10-19     4 1998-10-28
4:    12    1 1999-03-21    11 1999-10-22     4 1998-02-07
```

I’d like to count, for each id, the number of times a certain code (e.g. code=11) appears within a certain time interval (e.g. >1998-07-01).

I have tried different stuff, searched here for answers … eventually became less ambitious and ended up trying this (which still doesn’t work :():

```
n_id <- length(my_data$did)
output <- matrix(0,n_id,1)
for (i in 1:n_id) {
   for (j in 1:3) {
      if (my_data$code.[[i]][j] == 11 & my_data$date.[[i]][j]>as.Date(”1999-01-01”)) {trait[i] <-trait[i]+1}
   }
}
output
```

I’d like the output to look like this:

> output
>            [,1]
>       [1,]    2
>       [2,]    1
>       [3,]    0
>       [4,]    1

I hope someone can help me before I go nuts (also, I am sure there must be a more effecient way to do this than to loop through the data as I attempted above)